# How to use angular ng-repeat for following JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to match `headfield` values with `datafield`, and have to fetch corresponding value into table data.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th ng-repeat="ReportsHead in ReportsHeadList">
         {{ReportsHead.headerfield = ReportsHead.headfield}}
       </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="ReportsData in ReportsDataList" 
         ng-if="ReportsHead.headerfield == ReportsData.datafield">           
           {{ReportsData.value}}        
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JSON Data :**

```
$scope.ReportsHeadList = [
    {
      'headfield':'Contact Name'
    },
    {
      'headfield':'Phone'
    },
    {
      'headfield':'Email'
    }
];

$scope.ReportsDataList = {
    [
      {
        'datafield':'Contact Name',
        'value':'Gunaseelan'
      },
      {
        'datafield':'Phone',
        'value':'8122911043'
      },
      {
        'datafield':'Email',
        'value':'G@gmail.com'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        'datafield':'Contact Name',
        'value':'Gunaseelan'
      },
      {
        'datafield':'Phone',
        'value':'8122911043'
      },
      {
        'datafield':'Email',
        'value':'G@gmail.com'
      }
    ]
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: generally, you can convert your JSON object to javascript array using this `Array.map` if you want

Answer (score 0):

First you should parse your Json with `JSON.parse(json)`, and assigment the result to variable. e.g:
`$scope.json = JSON.parse(json)`.

After, you can check for match headfield and data fields with for loop or map, e.g:

`for(i in headfield) {
       if (i === something) 
         return i
    }`

Hope the answar will help, if not leave a comment,

Good luck!